# Text too high within textbox only in IE

Tags: css, cross-browser

The textboxes in my HTML forms have a height of 30px, and the entered text appears in the vertical center of the textboxes, just as I want in every browser - except IE.

I've checked it in Chrome, FF and Opera. IE8 shows the entered text higher than the center which looks really bad. I tried playing around with the padding, margin and line-height, but cannot get the text to budge from the top edge.

Any suggestions on what CSS property do I need to edit to center the text? I could add it as a IE specific style, if needed.

The website in question is [lazydragonbooks.com](http://www.lazydragonbooks.com). Two forms immediately visible are the 'Register' and 'Login' forms.

**Chrome**

[image]

**IE 8**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, messing with IE8 developer tools I found that `setting padding-bottom: 0;` and `padding-top: 10px;` aligned the text correctly.

You would have to use a conditional statement to avoid messing up proper browsers. I would recommend using a separate stylesheet:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Within ie8.css..

```
   input[type="text"] {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

This is of course specific to an input with the set height that you are using.

Comment: Your answer is better, I am working on a really crappy laptop, and for some reason when I tried the padding-top trick it just didn't appear to work.  Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin or padding like this for IE

```
*padding-top:/*px*/;
*margin:/*px*/;
```