# Textinput cursor is too high. What can I do about it?

Tags: html, css, textinput

My textinput looks like this:

[image]

Here is my CSS::

```
.searchBox input[type=text]{
    left: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 7px 0 8px;
    width: 280px;
    color: #828483;
}
```

I have no idea which CSS Attribute could fix this.

Can you help me?

Comment: It's probably vertical-align, padding, or margin. But it's impossible to be sure without seeing (relevant parts of) your html/css code.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you better. Nobody likes guessing at problems.

Comment: Can you provide your CSS please? Sound like a issue with `font-size` and `line-height`.

Comment: IE right? See my answer to a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482418/text-too-high-within-textbox-only-in-ie/9482796#9482796

Comment: Line-height, padding... But you should show us some code so it won't be a guessing game.

Comment: No, Chrome.

Added CSS of the input.

Comment: Could you post the CSS of the searchBox as well, since that will affect the styling of its descendant. Also, what's your html? Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height`:

```
input {
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em; /* equal to the height to vertically-centre the text */
    /* other CSS */
}
```

Comment: This didnt work, the text is bigger now, but still mis-positioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
}
```